# How to Embed/ Display a PPT on SharePoint Intranet Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, document, fileviewer

I am trying to embed a ppt viewer into our company's internal shared site where internal users can easily view my team's software documentation. The company is fairly large, so we are trying to make it look very professional for when other teams visit my team's page for software documentation. I saw on a completely unrelated website their document viewer and I want to display our documents in a similar type of box.

Below is a screen shot of the document viewer that I want it to look like (identifying information blocked out). The document viewer option that comes standard with the SharePoint does not have the side panel that offers a glance to the other pages like this one does. I see similar document viewers on other websites as well, so I know it can be done!

[image: Goal Document View]

[image: Current PPT Web Part]

My questions are: Is it possible to embed a similar style of view into my own SharePoint using the "document viewer" web part in the SharePoint or will I need to use some other method? Also, is there a name for the goal style of document viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [File viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c) in SharePoint online to display the files on page. But, there is no way to show the side panel using this web part.

**Workaround**:

As a workaround you can use the [Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8) in SharePoint.

You can use the `iframe` code like below to embed the PPT in view mode on your page.

```
<iframe src="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/myteam/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7Bacdc9f3b-30c9-417a-85ec-1dc1f72e5806%7D&action=view" title="PPT" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can adjust the width & height of the `iframe` as per your requirements.

---

You can get the PPT URL to put in `src` attribute of above code by following below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint document library where you have uploaded the PPT
2. Click on the PPT name & it will open the file in new browser tab
3. Copy the URL of file up to `sourcedoc` query parameter like below:

   [image]
4. Append `&action=view` to the copied URL & add it to the `src` attribute.
5. Add embed web part on a page & paste the `iframe` code in it.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! I converted my PPT to a PDF and used your method. It is so close to perfect! I re-posted this question but asking about PDFs in this thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293883/embed-pdf-into-sharepoint-with-pages-view

Comment: Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way and I will look into your new question.